# Getting multiple JFrames with my JAVA code

Tags: java, swing, random, jframe

I know; this is getting bad and I did try to come up with a possible solution. Basically, my program is opening up multiple applets when it should open only one and not displaying any of the random math questions I want it to. This is the code I've got:

```
package RandomMathGame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RandomMathGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomProblemGenerator randomProblems = new RandomProblemGenerator(10);
        final int numberProblems = 10;
        int correctScore = 0;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel[] questionPanel = new JPanel[numberProblems];
        JPanel mainQuestionPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
       int answer;
        int correctAnswer;
        JLabel[] mathProblems = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JTextField[] mathAnswers = new JTextField[numberProblems];
        JLabel[] correctYesNo = new JLabel[numberProblems];
        final JLabel score = new JLabel(correctScore + "/10");
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        mainQuestionPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 10));

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberProblems; i++)
        {
            final int X = randomProblems.createNumberX();
            final int Y = randomProblems.createNumberY();

            mathProblems[i] = new JLabel("" + X + " * " + Y + " = ");
            mathAnswers[i] = new JTextField();

         String answerStr = mathAnswers[i].getText();

    if(answerStr.isEmpty()){

          correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Not a valid answer/answer field empty!");
    } else {

             answer = Integer.parseInt(mathAnswers[i].getText());
             correctAnswer = X * Y;

            if (answer == correctAnswer)
            {
                correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Correct answer; good job!");
                correctScore = correctScore + 1;
            }
            else
            {
               correctYesNo[i] = new JLabel("Incorrect answer; try again!");

            }
             questionPanel[i].add(mathProblems[i]);
             questionPanel[i].add(mathAnswers[i]);
             questionPanel[i].add(correctYesNo[i]);
             mainQuestionPanel.add(questionPanel[i]);
            }

        final int temp = correctScore;
      submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                score.setText("Score: " + temp + "/10");
            }
        });



        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(score);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        mainPanel.add(mainQuestionPanel);
        mainPanel.add(panel);
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setTitle("Random Math Game");
        gameFrame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        gameFrame.setContentPane(mainPanel);



        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple frames are caused by this `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberProblems; i++)
{
...
```

It's closed after the `JFrame` is created, so it makes multiple ones.  Probably should be closed here:

```
    final int temp = correctScore;
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            score.setText("Score: " + temp + "/10");
        }
    });
}  // <- CLOSE THE FOR LOOP HERE

panel.add(submit);
```

There may still be `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown from the loop, though (at least in my very brief experimentation).

This means you are requesting access to an array index that doesn't exist, e.g. your array is 4 elements long, and you want element `[16]`.  If I may be so bold as to troubleshoot this, I reckon it's coming from the `i <= numberProblems`.  It should probably be `i < numberProblems`.

Since array indexing starts at 0, the last element will be `theArray.length - 1`, not `theArray.length`.

Comment: Well, that helped...At least I'm not getting multiple windows now. And thanks for the tip about the i <= numberProblems thing. Now if I can just figure out how to get it to display math problems, I'll be happy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `gameFrame` is created (and displayed) within the for-loop. Try closing the loop before creating the `gameFrame` object.